# split CSV single line file with awk

Tags: awk

Single line CSV file (VoIP rates) need to be insert in mysql.
File pattern:

```
citycode01,city name01,rate01 citycode02,city name02,rate02 citycode0n,city name0n,rate0n
```

where FS="," and RS=" ".

how can I split single line into every destination in separate line or build straight sql insert file using AWK?

CSV file

```
1201,New Jersey,0.012500 1202,USA OUT,0.012500 1203,USA OUT,0.012500 1204,Manitoba,0.008000
```

Need to be modified to one destination record per line

```
1201,New Jersey,0.012500  
1202,USA OUT,0.012500  
1203,USA OUT,0.012500  
1204,Manitoba,0.008000
```

I got two first fields by `awk -F ',' '{print $1$2}' rates.csv`

```
1201 New Jersey
```

Third field I can cut by `awk -F '[, ]' '{print $4}' rates.csv`

```
0.012500
```

But I don't know how to nicely loop it in around a whole line.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F' ' -v RS=, 'NR>1 && 1==NR%2{print $1; printf "%s,",$2; next} {printf "%s,",$0}' rates.csv
1201,New Jersey,0.012500
1202,USA OUT,0.012500
1203,USA OUT,0.012500
1204,Manitoba,0.008000
```

Comment: Thanks John, worked nice even handles empty destination city names

Answer (score 2):

Given your new input:

```
1604999,Vancouver - BC,0.008000 1605,USA OUT,0.012500 1605397,USA,0.039000 1605475,,0.061000 1605477,,0.061000 1605692,,0.061000 1605715,,0.061000 1606,USA OUT,0.012500 1607,USA OUT,0.012500 1608,USA OUT,0.012500
```

With GNU awk for `FPAT`:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[0-9]+,[^,]*,[0-9.]+' -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1}1' file
1604999,Vancouver - BC,0.008000
1605,USA OUT,0.012500
1605397,USA,0.039000
1605475,,0.061000
1605477,,0.061000
1605692,,0.061000
1605715,,0.061000
1606,USA OUT,0.012500
1607,USA OUT,0.012500
1608,USA OUT,0.012500
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk -v ORS= '{gsub(/[0-9]+,[^,]*,[0-9.]+/,"&\n"); gsub(/\n /,"\n")}1' file
```

or if you prefer a loop:

```
$ awk '{
    while ( match($0,/[0-9]+,[^,]*,[0-9.]+/) ) {
        print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}' file
```

Comment: Thanks Ed worked great except, I didn't know there are some rates with empty city code name   1604999,Vancouver - BC,0.008000
1605,USA OUT,0.012500
1605397,USA,0.039000
1605475,,0.061000 1605477,,0.061000 1605692,,0.061000 1605715,,0.061000 1606,USA OUT,0.012500
1607,USA OUT,0.012500
1608,USA OUT,0.012500

Comment: Just change `[^,]+` in the REs to `[^,]*` since `+` means 1 or more non-commas while `*` means zero or more. I've tweaked my answer and I THINK what it's producing is probably the output you'd expect.

Comment: you're right, now all comes as expected thanks again for quick respond Ed

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to click on the check mark next to whichever answer you accept, if any.